# MariaDB: FULLTEXT-indexed mediumblob super slow when ORDER BY datetime. How to faster? :)

Tags: sql, mariadb, full-text-search, query-optimization

**MariaDB:**

*FULLTEXT-indexed mediumtext ...super slow ...when ORDER BY datetime.*

How to faster? :)

Here is how I created the table:

```
CREATE TABLE data (
    primary int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    text mediumtext,
    datetime datetime
);
```

And here is how I created the FULLTEXT index:

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX data ON data(text);
```

And here is how I created the datetime index:

```
ALTER TABLE `data` ADD INDEX `datetime` (`datetime`);
```

Now a query might look like:

```
SELECT *
FROM database
WHERE MATCH (text)
AGAINST ('keyword' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
ORDER BY datetime DESC;
```

but the response time is presumably not ideal (takes minutes to respond, where a response w/o the ORDER BY statement is nearly instant).

i tried to create an combined index like this:

```
ALTER TABLE `database` ADD INDEX `inclusive` (`text`,`datetime`);
```

...only to generate this error:

> BLOB/TEXT column 'text' used in key specification without a key length

*ps.  i am not looking to solve this issue - i understand why we see this.*

again, this works super fast:

```
SELECT *
FROM database
WHERE MATCH (text)
AGAINST ('keyword' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
;
```

but when I add the "ORDER BY datetime DESC", to sort the FULLTEXT-indexed "text" column results:

```
SELECT *
FROM database
WHERE MATCH (text)
AGAINST ('keyword' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
ORDER BY datetime DESC;
```

wow, it takes minutes to return a result.

might anyone know i could speed things up a bit?

*thank you in advance,*

Comment: a fulltext index works on text, blobs are binary data.

Comment: besides you need to MATCH the text see https://mariadb.com/kb/en/full-text-index-overview/

Comment: Since SQL includes data definition, a [mcve] for an [SQL question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/90527) should include [DDL](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) statements for sample tables (rather than an ad hoc table specification) and [DML](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language) statements for sample data (rather than a dump or ad hoc format). Desired results don't need to be presented as sample code, as results are the output of code and not code themselves.

Comment: Seeing the EXPLAIN plan for the query might help. The basic problem though is that the query planner can only use one index per table at a time, and here it seems to have decided on that using an index for the sorting required by ORDER BY makes more sense than using the FULLTEXT index for the WHERE condition.

You may be able to fool it using a subquery construct: ```SELECT *
FROM (SELECT * FROM database
WHERE text = "keyword" ) _tmp
ORDER BY datetime DEC;```

Comment: >a fulltext index works on text, blobs are binary data. – nbk
>
>besides you need to MATCH the text see mariadb.com/kb/en/full-text-index-overview – nbk

yes, you are correct in both cases - i have edited my question to reflect the corrections.   thank you.

Comment: >SQL question should include DDL statements for sample tables (rather than an ad hoc table specification) - outis

yes, you are correct - i have edited my question to reflect the corrections.  thank you.

Comment: >You may be able to fool it using a subquery construct: SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM database WHERE text = "keyword" ) _tmp ORDER BY datetime DEC;  - Hartmut Holzgraefe

PART 1/3:

Yes, thank you - this is more along the lines of what I was looking for - as you suggested:

`SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM database WHERE MATCH (text) AGAINST ('keyword' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) ) _tmp ORDER BY datetime DEC;`

And it does seem to work!

Comment: >You may be able to fool...

PART 2/3:

HWOEVER:

1. I believe this is ultimately the same (in process) as my original statement:

`SELECT * FROM database WHERE MATCH (text) AGAINST ('keyword' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) ORDER BY datetime DESC;`

Comment: >You may be able to fool it...

PART 3/3:

2.  upon further testing, my original statement is now also responding promptly - yay?

`SELECT * FROM database WHERE MATCH (text) AGAINST ('keyword' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) ORDER BY datetime DESC;`

Sorry to say, I have no idea what changed - perhaps:

- some addition indexing (in columns that I did not exemplify in this post);

- some addition sql.conf / cache tuning;

In any event, thank you kindly those who took the time to reply.

Comment: @nsdb please don’t update the question with an answer. Remove the answer from the question and post a self answer.

Answer (score 0):

**FINAL SOLUTION:**

After further testing / sql.conf tuning (perhaps) we noticed the original query began to respond promptly:

```
SELECT *
FROM database
WHERE MATCH (text)
AGAINST ('keyword' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
ORDER BY datetime DESC;
```

Thank you.